# why tcp LAST_ACK state not wait 2 MSL

Tags: networking, tcp

We all know, by default, in TCP protocol, if one side in TIME_WAIT state, it will wait 2 MSL and then go to CLOSED state.

But why not LAST_ACK state wait 2 MSL before turn to  CLOSED state, actualy it turn to CLOSED state as soon as it received the last ACK packet.

In TIME_WAIT state, i think it have two purpose to wait 2 MSL:

- make sure all the packet for this tcp connection in the network have died or reach target side
- make sure the other side of this tcp connection have received the last ACK packet

But it seems LAST_ACK state should also need to make sure all the packet in the network have reach the target side, so it also need to wait for 2 MSL.

Comment: What should it wait for? When the last ACK packet is received, both sides know the connection is really closed. There is no further need for TIME_WAIT.

Comment: there maybe any packets delay and remain in the network?

Comment: There can't be any more packets, and if there are there is no harm in sending an RST instead of an ACK in reply, as we know the peer has.closed the connection.

Answer (score 0):

The `LAST_ACK` state on the passive opener/closer side is changed to `CLOSED` after it receives the last `ACK` from the active opener/closer - that is this state transition is triggered explicitly and, at that point, we're sure there are no more packets in flight coming from the active side because they have already said so (by sending the `FIN` packet before which the passive side confirmed by sending `ACK`).

It's only the active side that has to wait because it doesn't have the final confirmation that the last `ACK` that they sent was indeed sent (again, that ACK will make the passive side to move to the CLOSED state).
So to make sure that the `ACK` is received it waits `2 * MSL` before automatically moving from the `TIME_WAIT` state to `CLOSED`.

As Stevens says in TCP/IP Illustrated (Vol 1, 2nd ed.) on p. 619:

> When TCP performs an active close and sends the final ACK, that connection must stay in the TIME_WAIT state for twice the MSL. **This lets resend the final ACK in case it is lost**.
> The final ACK is resent not because the TCP retransmits ACKS (they do not consume sequence numbers are are not retransmitted by TCP) but because the otherwise will retransmit its FIN (which does consume a sequence number).

I think it's also helpful to include the state transitions picture from the book:
[image]